# Google Cast Receiver API for Android/iOS

Tags: google-cast-sdk

We are creators of a music player app and would like to extend our app
with the Google Cast (Audio) receiver capability.

Currently the Receiver API is a JavaScript API, which allows access to the visalization of the receiver part only, no chance to get to the raw audio data...

Is there a plan to provide a public or private API to be used in mobile apps?
I know, there were similar questions already (e.g. [Implementing Google cast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588654/implementing-google-cast-receiver)), but maybe there is an updated answer for this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Casting to an Android or iOS app is not supported by the Cast SDK.